# Flutter: check if a text string is in a web page?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

Let's say I want my flutter app to receive a URL as input, make a connection to the URL, then return a bool indicating whether the word is present in a web page.

**Example**: let's say https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html is the input, and the flutter app will return *True* or *False* if "EXERCISE" is found in the page.

What packages are helpful to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could attempt to make a HTTP request to the provided request. When the response is valid, you could go through the received html code and check whether a word exists in it.

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = Uri.parse('https://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html');
var response = await http.get(url);

if (response.body.toString().contains('exercise')) {
  // The word was found on the page.
}
```

Comment: This is totally it. Thank you very much for helping me dive back in!

Comment: Happy to help :)